# Drop down menu when click on the icon- ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a `Navbar` and i am using the condition that if `userstatus` is true(i.e user is signedin) then it will show the `user-icon` otherwise `signin`, i am looking to achieve that when i click in the `user-icon` or `singin`, it will show the drop down menu where i will later use it for logout button. i am struggling to find how will i achieve this, i can see at https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/ that i can implement but here i want to use my `own icon(glyphicon glyphicon-user)` rather the `rectangle box`.

[image]

- I am looking to achieve the below but instead of `Dropdown button` i am looking to use the `user-icon`

[image: Drop down button]

any suggestion/pointers please.

-Snippet of code

```
 <li>
             <a className="active" href="/signin">
               {userstatus ? (
                 <a
                   className=" signin-icon glyphicon glyphicon-user    
   "
                 ></a>
               ) : (
                 <a>SIGNIN</a>
               )}
             </a>
             
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

First solution which i don't recommend is to over ride the bootstrap css which will be alot and hustle you don't need starting from resting all the css and `!important` alot of css

second choice is to use your own dropdown which i find it lot easier than doing all this previous solution hustle .

incase you are using react hooks for ex :

```
const [isDropdownOpend , setDropdownOpen ] = useState(false);
const [list , setList] = useState([1,2,3])
const toggleDropDown = () => setDropdownOpend = !isDropdownOpend
const DropDownlist = () =>  useMemo(() =>list.map(el=><div>el</div>)
return (
<>
<button class="signin-icon glyphicon glyphicon-user  " onClick={toggleDropDown}>
{isDropdownOpend  ?DropDownlist():false}
</>
)
```

Comment: Thanks Aly, could you please explain this bit `const DropDownlist = () =>  useMemo(() =>list.map(el=><div>el</div>)` as i am struggling to understand how it is working here. and why we need two arrow functions in this code line.

Comment: as i understand the first arrow function `const DropDownlist = () =>` is a call back when ever user click and the last arrow function is `() =>list.map(el=><div>el</div>)` is the .map function is iterating in each element of list but whats the reason of the middle arrow function `() =>  useMemo(...)`, also the code is not working(drop down is not showing ) not sure if it is still missing something in it.

Comment: for the first call back yes you are right you can remove the extra call back `()=>`  , and for the error you have please give me more details about it

Comment: I have implemented the above code, but `useMemo(` it is saying that it is not define, not user how you are using it here

Comment: just import it 
` import { useMemo } from 'react' `

Answer (score 0):

Add these class here

```
<Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" className="bg-white border-0 p-0" variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
    <ADD YOUR ICON HERE>
  </Dropdown.Toggle>
```

css

```
.dropdown-toggle:after {
   border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the above link you mentioned you can change here:

```
<Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
    {* you icon code here *} (//in my case I used <FaBeer /> )
  </Dropdown.Toggle>

  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

and change the actions like you wanted inside Dropdown.Menu tag

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve this. A little bit of googling will reveal a lot of those ways. However, you can do this with pure css by using a div and having menu items and menu button inside it. Menu items will remain hidden as long as the parent div isn't hovered.

```css
.dropdown {
  width: 100px;
  background: purple;
}
.dropdown .item {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .item{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button>
Button
</button>
<div class="item">
<p>
item 1
</p>
</div>
</div>
```